# expressing 'among' in japanese

Tags: grammar

Sports (de ha/ni ha)soccer ga ichiban suki desu.

Which one is correct?
What is either of them used to express?

Comment: Thanks for seconding that.IME is the issue I face.Besides,i believe that the question was clear enough for the information sought.

Comment: Modern OSs [come with input methods](http://superuser.com/q/796497), and there are [many other free input methods you can use](http://www.google.co.jp/intl/ja/ime/), and you can actually use [Google Translate](https://translate.google.com/) as an input method as well.

Comment: "Sports"?  "Soccer"? Why do you need to mix in English words in their English spelling?

Answer (score 4):

In this sense (the domain for a superlative), "among" can be expressed by 〜で or 〜の中で:

> スポーツ**では**サッカーが一番好きです。

The domain can be anything that makes sense in context.  If you're describing the most or best in the world, then you can say 世界で.  If it's the most or best yet, you can say 今までで.  If it's the most or best out of a list of choices, you can say ＡとＢとＣの中で.

By the way, your sentence would probably not be translated into English using "among", so please keep in mind that it's only an approximate gloss.

References:

- Makino and Tsutsui's *Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar*, p.148
- Martin's *Reference Grammar of Japanese*, p.142
- Iwasaki's *Japanese: Revised Edition*, p.118

Comment: Thanks.
What is 'ni ha' used for then?
Is it a grammatical 'construct'?

Comment: Lots of things. Locations in existential constructions, subjects in dative subject constructions, topicalized agents in passives, destinations with verbs of giving, topicalized adjuncts indicating purpose, source/cause, etc.  That question is too broad to be answered here.  (The English grammatical term is "construction" rather than "construct", technically.)

Comment: I've been seeing a lot of ～のうちで too used for "among"